# remove debug strings in release build

Tags: c, debugging, release, armcc, rvds

I use a `LOG_DEBUG` function to print debug information to the screen. I used a `#define _DEBUG` to disable `LOG_DEBUG` function by defining `_DEBUG` FLAG in compile time (release time). but linux `strings` commands of release build app still shows debug strings which exists in the compiled app. so what is the alternatives to eliminate arguments of `LOG_DEBUG`?

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define LOG_DEBUG(fmt, ...) printf("[D][%s:%d %s]", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define LOG_DEBUG(fmt, ...)
#endif


LOG_DEBUG("this is a debug string");     // "this is a debug string" exists in app release build yet
```

the compiler I use: `ARM/Thumb C/C++ Compiler, RVCT3.1 [Build 569]`

optimization: `-O3`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the compiler name and version. Have you tried changing the optimization settings?

Comment: I guess *one* way would be to surround **each** debug with an `#ifdef`, but I assume you don't want to do that ;)

Comment: there's a huge number of function calls, I'm looking for a cleaner way

Comment: @Manidevs Hence the winky face :D

Comment: What you are currently doing is the standard way of handling this situation.  In a build that doesn't contain _DEBUG then that string should disappear.   Why not generate the .i file and see if the string exists there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using [stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/cpp/Stringification.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define _DEBUG

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define LOG_DEBUG(str) do { printf("[D][%s:%d %s] ", \
                               __FILE__, \
                               __LINE__, \
                               __FUNCTION__); \
                            puts(#str); } while(0)
#else
#define LOG_DEBUG(str)
#endif

int main() {
  LOG_DEBUG(this is a debug string);
  return 0;
}
```

**Note:** I tested this in clang, which doesn't exhibit the behaviour you described.

Comment: maybe this is just a armcc issue